# Prove that $C(X \times Y) = A \times C(Y) \cup C(X) \times B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is an exercise that I found in book about set theory:

Assume that $X \subset A$ and $Y \subset B$.

Prove that:

$$
C(X \times\ Y) = A \times\ C(Y) \bigcup C(X) \times B
$$

This seems to be false without defining the universe. For instance, $\emptyset \in C(X \times Y)$ which is definitely not in $A \times\ C(Y) \bigcup C(X) \times B$ because this set only contains ordered pairs. Am I wrong?

Comment: What is $C(-)$ supposed to be?

Comment: The complement of $A$ in $S$. The set of all elements that belong to $S$ but not belong to $A$ .

Comment: The empty set doesn't appear to be a *member* of any of these sets, necessarily.

Comment: How can $(s,t)$ *fail* to be in $X \times Y$?  Either $s \in X$ is wrong [but $t$ is still in $B$] or $t \in Y$ is wrong [and similarly].  That's the right-hand side.

Comment: What book, incidentally?

Comment: Let's say that $S$ is the set of all the possible things. Therefore,  $\emptyset \in S$.     $C(X \times Y)$ is the set of all the elements that are in $S$ but are not in $X \times Y$. Empty set is in $S$ and not in $X \times Y$.

Comment: Bart Mendelson. Introduction to Topology.

Comment: @Likepineapple Heh! Yes, I've just checked by own copy. Page 5 (Ch 1 sect 3): "The set $S$ may be fixed throughout a given discussion, in which case the complement of $A$ in $S$ may simply be called the complement of $A$ and be denoted $C(A)$." However, in the case of this exercise, the superset is not obviously defined. Having said that, I sailed through this exercise without noticing your concern. Hi ho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is implicit that:

- the complement of $X$ is meant to be with respect to $A$
- the complement of $Y$ is meant to be with respect to $B$
- the complement of $X \times Y$ is meant to be with respect to $A \times B$.

Is there something in the book you're getting this from that says something like: in absence of any other overriding statement, if it has been specified that $X$ is a subset of $A$, then when defining $C(X)$ it "implicitly means" $C_A(X)$.

IMO this is a bit careless. A better book would be more careful to specify these things.

Comment: it does indeed.